# Replace '\n' in String variable to <br /> so that it shows line break when displayed in <td>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textarea in React that also accepts newLine characters. It is correctly stored in mongoDB with the newLine characters. When I retrieve it back to React and try to display it in table `<td>`, it shows with spaces. But if I put it on console, it is correctly shown. I guess that is because in HTML newline character is `<br >`. How can I do this?

I tried replacing '\n' with `<br>` using replace(), but then `<br>` gets concatenated as a string literal.

**"items" shown in mongoDB**

[image: items shown in mongoDB]

**How its displayed in table**

[image: How its displayed in table]

**Correctly shown in console**

[image: Correctly shown in console]

**Code**

[image: Code]

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: Try to wrap items content with <pre> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MrBens suggested, the simplest solution is to use the [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) (preformatted text) tag.  For example:

```
 <td><pre>This is
 two lines</pre></td>
```

Would result in:

> This is

> two lines

There's also a similar CSS style, `whitespace: pre` or `whitespace: pre-wrap`. The MDN has [details about that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) also.